# unintended result of memcpy

Tags: c++

I have the following code. I'm a newbie and would like to know what's wrong with the code below. The intent is to get the mac value from the function getMac correctly to the main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void getMac(unsigned char *);

int main()
{
    unsigned char mac[6];
    getMac(mac);
    printf("back to main(), mac is %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n",
        mac[0],mac[1],mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
}

void getMac(unsigned char *mac)
{
    unsigned char eth[] = "44:bg:23:1f:20:77";
    printf("eth: %s\n", eth);
    memcpy(mac, eth, 6);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Is it c or c++?

Comment: `eth` is clearly greater than six characters.

Comment: `eth` is obviously longer than 6 bytes, so you only copy a small part of it. `memcpy` doesn't do any translations, it just copies bytes.

Comment: memcpy() will not do what you seem to want.  You need to parse that 'eth' string and then sscanf those ASCII-hex pairs as  unsigned chars.

Comment: What you've got is NOT c++ it's actually c with the exception that you have <iostream> and <string> included. Now for the problem, hint: use `printf("size of the eth array: %i\n", sizeof(eth));` in your `getMac` function right before the `memcpy` and see what pops out.

Comment: You could probably do it with one scanf(), given that format.

Comment: `memcpy` has no idea that what you want to do is break up that string into 6 pieces by using the `:` character as a delimiter-- memcpy can't read minds.  That's why your program doesn't work as you expected, as `memcpy` copies the number of `bytes` specified to the destination, not the number of "logical pieces".

Comment: Use std::string!

Comment: BTW, I don't think `bg` is a valid byte.

Answer (score 3):

If you copy 6 bytes of `"44:bg:23:1f:20:77"`, then you get `['4', '4', ':', 'b', 'g', ':']`. Apparently, that's not you were expecting to get. That's what's wrong with your code: You're expecting `memcpy` to do something other than copy bytes.

> The intent is to get the mac value from the function getMac correctly to the main.

One way to get the value from the function correctly would be to copy the entire string, not just the first 6 bytes. Another is to convert the hexadecimal strings into integer representation. A third option would be to have the original mac in an integer representation in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

A MAC address consists of 6 bytes, but the **text** that you have (`"44:bg:23:1f:20:77"`) is longer than 6 bytes. That's a valid **text** representation for a MAC address, but if you want the **numeric** values you have to translate each of those six fields (including the probably erroneous `bg`) into values. I don't want to write a parser here, but in general what you need to do is:

```
mac[0] = std::stoul("44", 0, 16);
mac[1] = std::stoul("bg", 0, 16); // ?
mac[2] = std::stoul("23", 0, 16);
mac[3] = std::stoul("1f", 0, 16);
mac[4] = std::stoul("20", 0, 16);
mac[5] = std::stoul("77", 0, 16);
```